# Import product images via csv issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import, script

I made a product script import and I can't add images for products.
I used this to import images:

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
     try{
       .....
    ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>[], 'values'=>[])) //media gallery initialization
    ->addImageToMediaGallery('/media/catalog/product'.$image,['image','thumbnail','small_image'], false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
     ......

    $product->save();

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo '<pre>';var_dump($e);

}
```

I used this: `$path='media/catalog/product'.$image;` for testing and it returns me this path:  **media/catalog/product/1/3/131-kio-6913_1.jp**g and this is the real location, where my pictures are saved.

When I run the script, I received this message: "Images does not exist", even the image it's there.

My machine run on windows and I checked the permissions and everything looks fine.
Does anyone why I have this issue?